# Custom generic class, method name expected

Tags: c#, class

I'm creating a custom generic class for an assignment in school. I'm stuck at the moment and i would greatly appreciate some help with the following error.

I'm adding the parameter obj to the array. The problem is that the obj will never change, thus if the object that i is "cake" all indexes in the array will say cake, and not the other string as-well.

```
   class minlist<T>
{
    T[] storage = new T[3];

 public void Add(T obj) 
    {
        if (storage.Length != 3)
        { 
            storage[0] = obj;
            storage[1] = obj;
            storage[2] = obj;
            storage[3] = obj;
         }
```

I figured that it would solve the problem if i made obj an array as-well. Thus being able sort each string in a different index, i would put cake in 0 and pie in 1 etc.

When i edit the parameter in the public void add(T obj) and make it public void add(T []obj)

I also have the add the indexes for the obj.

```
            storage[0] = obj[0];
            storage[1] = obj[1];
            storage[2] = obj[2];
            storage[3] = obj[3];
```

In main where i want to add something to the list it usually looks like this, without the changed parameter in the add method.

```
        minlist<authorinfo> aif = new minlist<authorinfo>();
        aif.Add(new authorinfo("The Count of Monte Cristo","Alexandre", "Dumas", 1844));
```

when i change the add parameter to []obj i must i do the following in main.

```
        minlist<authorinfo> aif = new minlist<authorinfo>();
        aif.Add(new authorinfo[0]("The Count of Monte Cristo","Alexandre", "Dumas", 1844));
```

The problem here is that the [0] doesn't work. I get an error that says method name expected. I got no clue what to do.

Sorry if the question is a-bit confusing.

Comment: This is to do with your class definition of `authorinfo`. If the first one works and the second does not use the first, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should restructure your class. A single `authorinfo` is not an array of `authorinfo`s.

Your add method accepts a single item. If you keep track of the location of the next empty item you can create your list:

```
 class MinList<T>
    {
        T[] items;
        int position;
        public MinList()
        {
            items = new T[3];
            position = 0;
        }

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            items[position] = item;
            position++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, i know its quite messy. I was going to clean it up. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Your minlist class holds objects of - in your sample's case - authorinfo. Each entry in the list class should be a single authorinfo object - OK?

So your first sample was correct for calling it:

```
aif.Add(new authorinfo("The Count of Monte Cristo","Alexandre", "Dumas", 1844));
```

(for starting purposes it might be easier to visualize if you write that like this:

```
authorinfo info = new authorinfo("The Count of Monte Cristo","Alexandre", "Dumas", 1844); 
aif.Add(info);
```

Makes it clearer that you're adding a single object.)

Since you are adding a single object, not an array of objects, your first attempt at the declared method was correct:

```
public void Add(T obj)
```

The problem now is how to store the items. Because you're using a fixed array length, you have no way of knowing how many items have been stored so far - so you also need to maintain in your class a count of how many items have actually been stored so far - start it at 0, use it as the next free index to store the item at, and then increment it ready for next time.

If you can get that working, your next problem is... what happens if the user tries to add more items than your fixed array can hold? Since this is an assignment, I'll leave it at that for you to try and work on.

Hope that helps.